# Residue from boiling bottled water

Tags: water

I boil natural spring water (Evian) in a stainless steel kettle and there is a white residue left behind that I can wipe off with a wet paper towel. What is this?
I also notice residue floating in water remaining on bottom of kettle. This does not happen with regular tap water.

Comment: Both spring water and tap water will contain dissolved minerals, e.g. calcium carbonate. Potable water just needs to be feed of poisons and reasonably sterile. Typically potable water isn't pure.

Comment: on the bottle there is usually a list of the mineral content. You've just isolated those minerals.